# error:"error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/layout_anchorGravity' with config ''.in android studio?

Tags: java, android, sdk

I am using the android studion 3.4.1(latest version). I have imported a project which needs:
Android SDK v23
Android Build Tools v23.0.2
Android Support Repository v23.3.0

I have done all the updates needed but now while running the program I am facing the issue.

I'am getting an error:

> error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/layout_anchorGravity' with config ''.
>   The following is my build.gradle(Module:app) file.

```
  android {
     compileSdkVersion 23 
      ....}

    .... 
  dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:+'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
   //noinspection GradleCompatible
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0-alpha1'
   implementation 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
  }
```

Please help me out with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you should do is migrate your app to AndroidX by going to Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX on the menu bar. This link might be helpful
[Migrating to AndroidX | Google Developers](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

Comment: Yes it worked.I also had to change "compilesdkversion 23" to "compilesdkversion 28" before migrating.